# Allowing javascript function to accept any number of arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I would like the below function to be more flexible and accept multiple callbacks to other functions if they are defined in the arguments.

```
$(function() {
    function icisDashBox(colorElem, thisWidth, thisHeight, completeCallBack) {
        $(colorElem).colorbox({
        transition: 'none',
        innerWidth: thisWidth,
        innerHeight: thisHeight,
        opacity: '0.5',
        onOpen: function() { 

        },
        onLoad: function() { 

        },
        onComplete:function() { 
            $('#cboxLoadedContent').wrap('<div id="icis_dialog_msg" />'); 

            completeCallBack();

        },
        onCleanup: function() { 

        },      
        onClosed: function() {
            $('#cboxLoadedContent').unwrap(); 
        }
    });
}

icisDashBox('.example9', '500', '500', completeFunction);

function completeFunction() {

    var fooClass = $("#colorbox").addClass("FOO");

    var barClass = $("#colorbox").addClass("BAR");

    var ajaxCnt = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.payso.me.uk",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
            $("#colorbox").addClass("AJAX SUCCESS");
        }
    });

    return {
        x : fooClass,
        y : barClass,
        z : ajaxCnt                         
    };
}
```

So in an ideal world my function would look like this without explicitly declaring any arguments:

```
function icisDashBox() { function code here }
```

Is this possible?  Also if the arguments are not defined how do i handle that?

For example if one call to the function has several callbacks defined and another only has one is there a way of handling the lack of presence of callbacks.

Cheers,

:)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use the keyword [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Arguments) which is an array of the passed arguments, like this:

```
function myFunc() {
   if(arguments.length > 0)     //be sure to check if there are any...
     var arg1 = arguments[0];
}
```

**However**, a much better approach is to accept an object, e.g.:

```
function myFunc(settings) {
   settings = settings || {};   //in case it was called as just: myfunc()
   var something = settings.something || "default value";
}
```

You'd call it like this:

```
myFunc({ something: "value", somethingElse: "otherValue" });
```

This approach allows you to accept any number of arguments as well, but also have any optional, without a bunch of `myFunc(null, null, null, "value")` type calls to provide only the parameter you want, plus they're named making this *much* more maintainable IMO.  [Here's an edited version of the plugin to demonstrate this](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/7NZ7M/1/).

Comment: Thanks Nick i will look into this approach i think.

I assume that 'settings' becomes global due to the omission of 'var' and would need to be namespaced?

Comment: @RyanP13 - Nope not global, since it's a parameter name it's local to the function, you're already covered there :)

Comment: +1 For passing an object, also keep in mind that whenever you encounter a situation where you can't remember the arguments(like for example your function takes 5 ints) refactor it to take an object.

Comment: Thanks to all for great answers.  This has been a massive help like you would not believe.

Have updated the code here to view:

http://jsfiddle.net/7NZ7M/

Comment: @Nick

Would i always have to pass functions to the 'callback' properties of the settings object?

I tried this and it seemed to work:

onLoadCall: $('body').prepend('<span class="prepend"/>'),

But i am not sure it should if you know what i mean?

Comment: @RyanP13 - Try something like this, more compact and easier to maintain :) http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/7NZ7M/1/

Comment: @RyanP13 - Yes you'd need anonymous functions, otherwise it runs the code immediately, so you'd need `onLoadCall: function() { $('body').prepend('<span class="prepend"/>'); }` as the option.  If it's a named function you'd just go `option: functioName`, no parenthesis.

Comment: @ Nick

Sorry what is going on here: if(typeof options.onCompleteCall == "function")
                  options.onCompleteCall.call(this);

Doesn;t look like a normal if statement and if we are alwasy passing functions, named or anonymous why is it needed?

Comment: @RyanP13 - It's checking that what was passed was a function, so if you did `onCompleteCall: "bob"`, it wouldn't blow up trying to do `"bob".call(this)`, since `string` doesn't have a `.call()` function...just a safety check :)

Comment: btw, the arguments object is not an actual array per se. For example, you cannot apply array operations like splice,pop etc.Ref:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Answer (score 8):

Use **arguments** variable.

```
function TestMe()
{
   var args = arguments;

   for (var a in args)
   {
     alert(args[a]);
   }
}
```

Now you can pass any number of arguments to `TestMe` function:

```
TestMe(1);
TestMe(1,2,3);
TestMe(1,2,3,4,5,6);
TestMe.apply(this, [1,2,3,4,5]);
```

etc.

Answer (score 7):

Just loop over the `arguments` object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Arguments

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to the spread operator now you can do something like this

```js
function myFunction(...params) {
  console.log(...params);
}

myFunction('Many arguments', 1, {two: 3}, ["four", 5]);

// to access one by one
function oneByOne(...params) {
  params.map(param => {
   console.log(param);   
  });
}

oneByOne('Many arguments', 1, {two: 3}, ["four", 5]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is possible, here's an example :

```
function myfunct()
{

  var arguments = myfunct.arguments;

  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
        {

                alert("Argument " + i + " value = " + arguments[i]);

            }

}
```

You can call this fonction by any number of arguments :

```
myfunct("foo");

myfunct("foo","bar");
```

Answer (score 1):

In more recent times you can now make use or the spread and rest operators as detailed here - [Pass unknown number of arguments into javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116608/pass-unknown-number-of-arguments-into-javascript-function)