# Pass unknown number of arguments into JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to pass an unknown number of arguments like:

```
var print_names = function(names) {
    foreach(name in names) console.log(name); // something like this
}

print_names('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
```

Also, how do I get the number of arguments passed in?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to send a variable number of arguments to a JavaScript function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959040/is-it-possible-to-send-a-variable-number-of-arguments-to-a-javascript-function)

Comment: So far [public override's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18197010/1151080) is the only one that describes how to **pass** an unknown number of arguments (into a function call) (using [`.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)). The others show how to **read** an unknown number of arguments (from within the function) (using [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)).

Answer (score 179, accepted):

### ES3 (or ES5 or oldschool JavaScript)

You can access the arguments passed to any JavaScript function via the magic `arguments` object, which behaves similarly to an array.  Using `arguments` your function would look like:

```
var print_names = function() {
     for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) console.log(arguments[i]);
}
```

It's important to note that `arguments` is **not** an array.  MDC has some good documentation on it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Functions#Using_the_arguments_object

If you want to turn `arguments` into an array so that you can do things like `.slice()`, `.push()` etc, use something like this:

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
```

### ES6 / Typescript

There's a better way!  The new [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) feature has your back:

```
var print_names = function(...names) {
    for (let i=0; i<names.length; i++) console.log(names[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed and at the same time short+simple answer :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I found this to be a helpful article explaining what's happening with `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)`: https://medium.com/@andrewsburke/array-prototype-slice-call-arguments-a94b04e74a4

Comment: How would you properly type the `...names`

Answer (score 29):

### ES6/ES2015

Take advantage of the [rest parameter syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters).

```
function printNames(...names) {
  console.log(`number of arguments: ${names.length}`);
  for (var name of names) {
    console.log(name);
  }
}

printNames('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
```

There are three main differences between rest parameters and the
arguments object:

- rest parameters are only the ones that haven't been given a separate name, while the arguments object contains all
  arguments passed to the function;
- the arguments object is not a real array, while rest parameters are Array instances, meaning methods like sort, map, forEach or pop can be applied on it directly;
- the arguments object has additional functionality specific to itself (like the callee property).

Comment: This makes perfect sense for web development that usually uses common PHP syntax.

Comment: Though (even more important in 2016 when the answer went up), recall that [there's no Internet Explorer support for spreads](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters#browser_compatibility) if you're not transpiling. Key gotcha I've seen too often: Devs use stuff like this in templates, which often aren't transpiled even when their TypeScript (typically) is.

Answer (score 13):

```
var 
print_names = function() {
    console.log.apply( this, arguments );
};

print_names( 1, 2, 3, 4 );
```

Answer (score 7):

```
function print_args() {
    for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++)
        console.log(arguments[i])
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a hidden object passed to every function in JavaScript called `arguments`.

You would just use `arguments.length` to get the amount of arguments passed to the function.

To iterate through the arguments, you would use a loop:

```
for(var i = arguments.length; i--) {
   var arg = arguments[i];
}
```

Note that `arguments` isn't a real array, so if you needed it as an array you would convert it like this:

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
```

Comment: Just note that it isn't a "real" array, it is an "array-like" object (with some special characteristics), but to use "Array methods" on it, you will need to convert it, e.g. `var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);`, `var args = Array.apply(null, arguments);`, etc, there are many ways...

Answer (score 4):

`arguments.length`. you can use a for loop on it.

```
(function () {
    for (var a = [], i = arguments.length; i--;) {
        a.push(arguments[i]);
    };
    return a;
})(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
```

Comment: @meder, I love using anonymous functions like that. Nice example! Also, are you missing a couple of semicolons there?

Comment: @meder, Semicolon insertion in JavaScript #ftf

Comment: @meder, indeed, just the semicolon after the `for` block is not really needed, however I would add one at the end of the last line.

Comment: Why do you have to put the function between ()?

Comment: @weng this gives the function higher precedence so it will be evaluated first, then the last `(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)` will execute it.

Comment: Is there any reason why you have it putting the arguments into the array in reverse? (a[0] = 8, a[1] = 7, a[2] = 6, etc...)

Comment: @weng, it's about `FunctionExpression` vs `FunctionDeclaration`, check [this article](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/).

Comment: @Archonix, I don't think there's any special reason, it's just a simple example... Replace the `push` call for `a[i] = arguments[i];` and everything will be Ok :)

Comment: @CMS, @Jacob - I typed this all in one line and then beautified it, that's why theres an extraneous semicolon after the for loop. Normally I would *never* include it.

Answer (score 2):

Much better now for ES6

```
function Example() {
    return {
        arguments: (...args) =>{
            args.map(a => console.log());
        }
    }
}

var exmpl = new Example();
exmpl.arguments(1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c');
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Rest parameters in ES6

```
const example = (...args) => {
  for (arg in args) {
    console.log(arg);
  }
}
```

Note: you can pass regular parameters in before the rest params

```
const example = (arg1, ...args) => {
  console.log(arg1);
  for (arg in args) {
    console.log(arg);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function using the spread/rest operator and from there on, you achieved your goal. Please take a look at the chunk below.

```
const print_names = (...args) => args.forEach(x => console.log(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the spread/rest operator to collect your parameters into an array and then the `length` of the array will be the number of parameters you passed:

```
function foo(...names) {
    console.log(names);
    return names;
}

console.log(foo(1, 2, 3, 4).length);
```

Using [BabelJS](https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUA6LYCGBbAUwGcBKRAbwChEbEIEi4AbAjJuAczV0NIG5qtAE4EoIIUh7EBAX0pA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Cstage-1&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.5.5&externalPlugins=) I converted the function to oldschool JS:

```
"use strict";

function foo() {
  for (var _len = arguments.length, names = new Array(_len), _key = 0; _key < _len; _key++) {
    names[_key] = arguments[_key];
  }

  console.log(names);
  return names;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let x = function(){
  return [].slice.call(arguments);
};

console.log(x('a','b','c','d'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best answer using spread operator :)

```
function sum(...nums)
{
    let total =0;
     for(num of nums)
     {
         total+=num;
     }
    console.log(total)
}
console.log(sum(2,4,5,6,7));
```

Answer (score -4):

I like to do this:

This will not help if you don't know the number of arguments, but it helps if you don't want to remember the order of them.

```
/**
 *  @param  params.one        A test parameter
 *  @param  params.two        Another one  
 **/
function test(params) {

    var one = params.one;
    if(typeof(one) == 'undefined') {
        throw new Error('params.one is undefined');
    }

    var two = params.two;
    if(typeof(two) == 'undefined') {
        throw new Error('params.two is undefined');
    }
}
```

Comment: The question was about unknown number of arguments.