# After getting unknown number of arguements, pass them to another function

Tags: javascript, methods

As a follow up to the below question, I have a need to send the arguments I received to another function.

[Pass unknown number of arguments into javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116608/pass-unknown-number-of-arguments-into-javascript-function)

For example:

```
myObj.RunCall("callName", 1,2,3,4,5);
myObj.RunCall("anotherCall", 1);
myObj.RunCall("lastCall");
```

where

```
runCall = function(methodName)
{
    // do something clever with methodName here, consider it 'used up'
    console.log(methodName);

    // using 'arguments' here will give me all the 'extra' args
    var x = arguments.length;

    // somehow extract all the extra args into local vars?
    // assume there were 4 (there could be 0-100)

    otherObj.DoIt(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);     // here i need to send those "extra" args onwards
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`.apply()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) lets you call a function with arguments that are in an array. So:

```
otherObj.DoIt(1,2,3);
// is equivalent to
otherObj.DoIt.apply(otherObj, [1,2,3]);
```

(The first argument to `.apply()` is the object that is to become `this` within the function you are calling.)

So you just need to create an array with the values from `arguments`, which you can get using `.slice()` to skip the first one:

```js
var runCall = function(methodName) {
    console.log("In runCall() - methodName is " + methodName);

    var extras = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
    otherObj.DoIt.apply(otherObj, extras);
}

// simple `otherObj.DoIt() for demo purposes:
var otherObj = { DoIt: function() { console.log("In DoIt()", arguments); }}

runCall("someMethod", 1,2,3);
runCall("someMethod", 'a', 'b');
runCall("someMethod");
```

Comment: ok, let me clarify a bit, because I dont know that there will be 4 exactly, i just want to send ANY extra ones i get to the other function

Comment: If they are "extra" arguments then what are the "base" arguments? I thought you meant that `arg1` - `arg4` were fixed, and then you wanted to add the ones from `arguments` after that.

Comment: does .apply() return the same thing the original function would have?

Comment: i want to consume the 1 named arguement (the methodname), the rest are to be passed to DoIt .

Comment: Yes, `.apply()` returns the original function's result. I've edited my answer to what I now understand you were asking, and included a demo. If `methodName` is the name of the function you want to call then `otherObj[methodName].apply(otherObj, [].slice.call(arguments, 1))`.