# JavaScript: Pass unknown number of arguments from one method to another

Tags: javascript, arguments, destructuring, spread

Here is what I would like to do. I have two methods, the first of which can accept any number of arguments. This method is an intermediary, it does not know how many arguments it is going to receive, but it needs to pass all its arguments along to another method. Obviously there is more code, but I have stripped this down to the bare minimum.

```
function acceptArguments(args) {
  secondFunction(arguments);
}
```

Normally, using this approach the second method accepts the arguments as an array

```
function secondFunction(param) {
  console.log(param);
}
```

Running this I would expect to see the following:

acceptArguments(1, 2, 3, 4) => and the output would be [1,2,3,4]

However what I would like to able to do is have the secondFunction method accept the parameters individually and not as an array, so it would look something like this:

```
function secondFunction(v1, v2, v3, v4) {
  console.log(v1, v2, v3, v4);
}
```

Running this I would expect to see the following, if I were to pass 1, 2, 3, 4 ad separate parameters to the method:

acceptArguments(args) => and the output would be 1, 2, 3, 4

My situation is that the secondFunction method is aware of how many arguments it will be receiving, but the acceptArguments method (which is an intermediary does not know or care how many arguments it is passing along.

I have tried, the following without result:

```
function acceptArguments() {
  secondFunction(...arguments);
}

function acceptArguments() {
  secondFunction(...Object.keys(arguments));
}

function acceptArguments() {
  secondFunction.apply(Object.keys(arguments));
}
```

Comment: Look up "rest parameters": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass unknown number of arguments into javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116608/pass-unknown-number-of-arguments-into-javascript-function)

Comment: @shkaper That question is about how to receive an unknown number of arguments, not how to pass them to the next function.

Comment: @sdgluck - I do not want an array, I want individual parameters in the receiving function.

Comment: @shkaper - no it does not.

Comment: `secondFunction(...arguments);` works for me.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think `Object.keys(arguments)` might work. The arguments are the values, not the keys.

Comment: @Barmar right. So, more like a combination of [how to pass](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1959040/5045563) and [how to receive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4116608/5045563)

Comment: @shkaper He already knows how to receive them, by using the `arguments` object. The question is only about how to pass them.

Comment: @Barmar, sorrry I meant Object.values, but yes I wasn't quite sure why I thought that would work lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rest syntax to collect all the arguments into an array in `acceptArguments` (which is preferred over using the `arguments` variable), and then spread those arguments into the call of `secondFunction`:

```js
function acceptArguments(...args) {
  secondFunction(...args);
}

function secondFunction(v1, v2, v3, v4) {
  console.log(v1, v2, v3, v4);
}

acceptArguments(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: Although this is preferred over `arguments`, the latter should work, and works for me.

Comment: Perfect thanks! I knew I was close, just couldn't quit sort it out.