# Run a function with the values from an array for unknown array and function parameter length in Javascript

Tags: javascript, scheme, racket

This function basically should behave like the apply-function in Scheme, just rebuild in Javascript.
So I have a given function f with n parameters and an array of length n.

Is there a way to call a function with the values of the array when I don't know how many parameters the function is going to have before hand?

For instance if the function was:

```
var f = function (x,y,z) {return x+y+z;};
```

And the Array was [1,2,3], is there a way to call f in a for loop or similar with the values without knowing beforehand how many params f is going to have?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass unknown number of arguments into javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116608/pass-unknown-number-of-arguments-into-javascript-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const a = (...args)=>  args.reduce((result,number)=> result+number);
```

You can use spread operator on a function and it can handle n number of parameters and if you try to use args inside the function it will be in a form of array and the order will be same as that of the parameter passed when calling the function

Comment: This is great but doesn't work in ES3. `Function.apply` along with the `arguments` keyword would work in that case, however.