# Pass arguments to function without spread (IE11)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, ecmascript-5

Imagine I have the following code:

```js
function log(level, message) {
  console.log(level + " " + message);
}

function supplyToLogger() {
  log(...arguments);
}

supplyToLogger("WARN", "This is a warning.");
```

How can I supply the `arguments` object to the `log` function without the spread operator? I need this to work in IE11, without the use of polyfills.

Comment: Also relevant: [Is it possible to send a variable number of arguments to a JavaScript function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1959040) | [What is the difference between call and apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1986896) | [Pass unknown number of arguments into javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4116608)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```js
function log(level, message) {
  console.log(level + " " + message);
}

function supplyToLogger() {
  log.apply(null, arguments);
}

supplyToLogger("WARN", "This is a warning.");
```