# I am trying to create a function and I don't know how many inputs it will require, whats the best way to account for this?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops

```
function totalLength(thk, dim) {
    var bendDeduction = 1.55 * thk;
    var lengthMinusBend = dim - bendDeduction;
    return lengthMinusBend;
}
```

This is the simplified version I have now. Basically, I want to be able to input several values for the dim input. currently, i am calculating the "dim" input outside of the function. The problem I am having is that I can't figure out a way to provide for the fact that the number of values I need to add to create the sum that is represented by the "dim" input will vary.

Also, this is currently only applicable for one bend. I want to be able to subtract the "bendDeduction" from each new input.

I am brand new to all of this, I am trying to wrap my head around all of this. I am thinking of some type of array and a for loop but I am so new to all of it I can't figure out exactly the way to write it. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass unknown number of arguments into javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116608/pass-unknown-number-of-arguments-into-javascript-function)

Answer (score 0):

use an "array" for the secod Argument :

```js
function totalLength(thk, ...dim )
  {
  let bendDeduction   = 1.55 * thk * dim.length
 
  return dim.reduce((t,d)=>t+d) - bendDeduction;
} 



console.log ( totalLength( 100, 200) )

console.log ( totalLength( 100, 200, 300) )
```

Answer (score 0):

First, declare a helper function that calculates the sum of an array

Then you can use [`Rest Parameters`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) to make the function accepts a variable number of arguments

```js
function sumArray(arr) {
    var res = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        res += arr[i];
    }
    return res;
}

function totalLength(thk, ...dim) {
    var bendDeduction = 1.55 * thk;
    var dimSum = sumArray(dim);
    var lengthMinusBend = dimSum - bendDeduction;
    return lengthMinusBend;
} 

console.log(totalLength(100, 80, 60, 20));
```

Comment: I am not supposed to include the thickness in the calculation of the sum. I have been messing with this for a while and I can't figure out how to exclude that. Im confused how sumArray calculates the sum of the values. What I really want is to calculate just the ...dim input, not the thk as well

Comment: nevermind, i figured it out. I needed the array to start at 0, not 1, so I changed i to 0 and it worked as I wanted. i dont know how or when i switched it to 1, but when I tried executing the code i messed it up. I had to also account for the total number of bends to subtract being the total number in the array - 2, i must have messed with it during that step.  Thank you so much for your help!