# How to sort object by key value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, contentful

I'm making a code to fetch content from contentful using AJAX. I've success retrieve data and display it, but something is not quite what I want. Because the content that I get is not in the same order as the contentful cms, so I add another field called `sequence`. So in my code I added a `sort()` and `Object.keys()` function before `forEach()`, but there is no error and data not appears ,does anyone know why data not appears?

If you want to try debugging, you can look at [This Codepen](https://codepen.io/fikryrmdhna/pen/oNqGeXd).

```js
function renderContentBySection(sectionName, appendElement, numberOfSkeleton, elementAttribute, elementClass){
  $.ajax({
    url : 'https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/r5mgd95bqsb5/environments/master/entries/1bI13SpZBBvgOgIk4GhYEg?access_token=CVel_r57GUqeTeaLyIsseXEAM1z1f-spXNKR-a2-huA',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data){
      const getData = data.fields

      if(getData[sectionName]) {
        if(getData[sectionName] && getData[sectionName].length) {
          getData[sectionName].forEach((item, index) => {
            getSingleEntry(item.sys.id)
          });
        }
      }
    }
  });
}

function getSingleEntry(contentId){
  $.ajax({
    url : `https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/r5mgd95bqsb5/environments/master/entries/${contentId}?access_token=CVel_r57GUqeTeaLyIsseXEAM1z1f-spXNKR-a2-huA`,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(dataKat){
    
      getAssetData(dataKat.fields.image.sys.id, dataKat.fields.sequence)

      $('.data-banner').append(JSON.stringify(dataKat.fields, null, 4))
      $('.data-banner').append('<br>');
    }
  });
}

function getAssetData(assetsId, sequenceId){
  $.ajax({
    url : `https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/r5mgd95bqsb5/environments/master/assets/${assetsId}?access_token=CVel_r57GUqeTeaLyIsseXEAM1z1f-spXNKR-a2-huA`,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(getAssetsData){
      
      $('.data-image').append(JSON.stringify(getAssetsData.fields, null, 4))
      $('.data-image').append('<br>');
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  renderContentBySection('mainBannerImage', '#carousel-inner', 1, 'banner', 'main-banner-item');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<pre class="data-banner">
  <h4>Get Data Main Banner:</h4>
</pre>
<br>
<pre class="data-image">
  <h4>Get Data for Each Image in Main Banner:</h4>
</pre>
```

Comment: The error means that `dataKat` isn't an array. Can you show an example of `console.log(typeof dataKat, dataKat)`?

Comment: you can see here on ```console``` tab https://codepen.io/fikryrmdhna/pen/oNqGeXd , i can't copy the console log here @Barmar

Comment: `dataKat` is an object, not an array. There's nothing to sort.

Comment: So, there's a way to sort object based on my sequence? @Barmar

Comment: You're just getting a single entry, how can you sort it? You need to get all the entries, put them in an array, and sort that.

Comment: Single entry that i mean in above (function) is only get the category (i.e main banner), but inside that, there are more than 1 content @Barmar

Comment: Now I see you changed the question, you changed what you're sorting. I'll look again.

Comment: `dataKat.fields.sequence` is just a single number, not an object. There's no `Object.keys(dataKat.fields.sequence)` to sort. Please update the question with a sample of the object you're trying to sort, and what result you expect to get.

Comment: i've edit post above with adding real data that i have. If you see data in ```Get Data for Each Image in Main Banner``` there's key ```sequence```, i have do data looping and like you saw, it's not sequentially. I want data in **Get Data for Each Image in Main Banner** sequentially base on ```sequence``` key @Barmar

Comment: I don't see any data in the question, just code. Post a sample of the JSON.

Comment: you've run the snippets? @Barmar

Comment: No, I expected you to paste the sample JSON into the question, not code that retrieves it.

Comment: There's nothing in each image to sort. I think you want to sort all the images, not sort one image at a time.

Comment: Ya, i want sort all of image based on sequence key @Barmar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246824/discussion-between-barmar-and-frankfurt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you completely changed the criteria, I will provide an answer for your second ask.

The key to working with multiple batches of asynchronous requests is to gather all the requests, and then listen for them all to complete. Then, do the same thing again with the next batch of requests.

Otherwise, your HTML will print **in the order the responses are returned** and it will seem random.

Once you have gathered all the completed requests, you can `sort()` them, then do a `forEach` through them.

```js
function listenForEntries(arrAllEntryRequests) {
    //set up a listener for when all requests have finished, using "spread operator" (...) to send all requests as parameters to when():
    $.when(...arrAllEntryRequests).done(
        //done:
        function (...arrAllEntryResponses) {
            let arrAllEntries = [];
            //console.log("arrAllEntryResponses", arrAllEntryResponses);

            arrAllEntryResponses.forEach((e) => {
                arrAllEntries.push(e[0].fields);
            });;

            //all images loaded, sort:
            arrAllEntries.sort((a, b) => (a.sequence < b.sequence ? -1 : 1));
            

            //sorting done, get asset data for each. This is also asyncronous so you need to do the same thing as above:    
            let arrAllAssetRequests = [];

            arrAllEntries.forEach((entryData) => {
                //console.log("entryData", entryData);

                $('.data-sequence').append(`
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    Sequence ID: ${entryData.sequence}<br>
                    Title Banner: ${entryData.title}
                  </li>
                </ul>`)
                
                let assetReqObj = getAssetData(entryData.image.sys.id, entryData.sequence);
                arrAllAssetRequests.push(assetReqObj);

            });

            listenForAssets(arrAllAssetRequests);
        }
    );
}

function listenForAssets(arrAllAssetRequests) {
    $.when(...arrAllAssetRequests).done(
        //done:
        function (...arrAllAssetResponses) {
            //all assets loaded, sort:
            arrAllAssetResponses.sort((a, b) => (a[2].sequence < b[2].sequence ? -1 : 1));

            arrAllAssetResponses.forEach((assetData) => {
                //console.log("assetData", assetData);

                if(assetData.length > 0) {
                    $('.data-assets').append(`
                    <ul>
                    <li>
                        Sequence ID: ${assetData[2].sequence}<br>
                        Title Banner: ${assetData[0].fields.title}<br>
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="${assetData[0].fields.file.url}">
                    </li>
                    </ul>`);
                } else {
                    console.error("Something wrong with assetData", assetData);
                }
            });
        }
    );
}

function renderContentBySection(sectionName, appendElement, numberOfSkeleton, elementAttribute, elementClass) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/r5mgd95bqsb5/environments/master/entries/1bI13SpZBBvgOgIk4GhYEg?access_token=CVel_r57GUqeTeaLyIsseXEAM1z1f-spXNKR-a2-huA',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            const getData = data.fields

            //move array to inside this function as it's the only place it will be used:
            let arrAllEntryRequests = [];

            if (getData[sectionName]) {
                if (getData[sectionName] && getData[sectionName].length) {
                    getData[sectionName].forEach((item, index) => {
                        arrAllEntryRequests.push(getSingleEntry(item.sys.id));
                    });

                    //once array of requests is created, listen for it to finish:
                    listenForEntries(arrAllEntryRequests);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

function getSingleEntry(contentId) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: `https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/r5mgd95bqsb5/environments/master/entries/${contentId}?access_token=CVel_r57GUqeTeaLyIsseXEAM1z1f-spXNKR-a2-huA`,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (dataKat) {
            //do nothing            
        }
    });
}

function getAssetData(assetsId, sequenceId) {
    let $xhr = $.ajax({
        url: `https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/r5mgd95bqsb5/environments/master/assets/${assetsId}?access_token=CVel_r57GUqeTeaLyIsseXEAM1z1f-spXNKR-a2-huA`,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (assetData) {
            //do nothing
        }
    });

    $xhr.sequence = sequenceId; //store the sequence for later

    return $xhr;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    renderContentBySection('mainBannerImage', '#carousel-inner', 1, 'banner', 'main-banner-item');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="data-sequence">
        <span> This is sequence data:</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="data-assets">
        <span> This is assets data:</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ahh, this is good. thanks for your help mate! sorry for my late response

Answer (score 1):

Because your data is loaded asyncronously, you will need to create a queue of your requests, and listen for them to all finish.

I have commented my code below so you can understand how it works.

First, you need to use the spread operator a lot `...`, to work with an unknown number of array elements.
(https://stackoverflow.com/a/35169449/1410567)

Second, you need to use `$.when(...array).done(function(...results) {` to know when the requests have finished.
(https://blog.kevinchisholm.com/javascript/jquery/using-jquery-deferred-to-manage-multiple-ajax-calls/)

Third, you need to use `Array.sort()` to sort the array of objects, comparing their `sequence`, and returning 1 or -1 to sort them.
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```js
//create an empty array to hold the queue:
let allImageRequests = [];

function listenForImages() {
  //set up a listener for when all requests have finished, using "spread operator" (...) to send all requests as parameters to when():
  $.when(...allImageRequests).done(
    //done:
    function (...arrAllImagesResp) {
      let arrAllImages = [];
      console.log("arrAllImagesResp", arrAllImagesResp);

      arrAllImagesResp.forEach((e) => { 
        console.log(e);
        arrAllImages.push(e[0].fields);
      });;

      //all images loaded, sort:
      arrAllImages.sort((a, b) => (a.sequence < b.sequence ? -1 : 1));

      console.log("done", arrAllImages);

      //sorting done, display results:
      $('.data-image').append("\n\n<strong>All Images Sorted:</strong> \n\n" + JSON.stringify(arrAllImages, null, 4));
    }
  );
}

$.ajax({
    url: 'https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/r5mgd95bqsb5/environments/master/entries/1bI13SpZBBvgOgIk4GhYEg?access_token=CVel_r57GUqeTeaLyIsseXEAM1z1f-spXNKR-a2-huA',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
    console.log("got data", data);
    
        const getData = data.fields.mainBannerImage

        $('.data-banner').append(JSON.stringify(getData, null, 4))
        $('.data-banner').append('<br>');

        getData.forEach((item, index) => {
            //add requests to our queue:
            allImageRequests.push(getImageAssets(item.sys.id));
        });
    
        listenForImages();
    }
})

function getImageAssets(assetId) {
    //I added a return here, so the XHR objects will be push()'d to the allImageRequests queue array:
    return $.ajax({
        url: `https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/r5mgd95bqsb5/environments/master/entries/${assetId}?access_token=CVel_r57GUqeTeaLyIsseXEAM1z1f-spXNKR-a2-huA`,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (assetsData) {
            const getAssetsData = assetsData.fields

            $('.data-image').append(JSON.stringify(getAssetsData, null, 4))
            $('.data-image').append('<br>');
        }
    })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<pre class="data-banner">
  <h4>Get Data Main Banner:</h4>
</pre>
<br>
<pre class="data-image">
  <h4>Get Data for Each Image in Main Banner:</h4>
</pre>
```

Comment: actually, i have 3 function with 3 ajax. I was implementing your code with my current code but there's an error. Cause ```allImageRequests.push(getDataAssets())``` pushing ```undefined ```data. I have edit my snippet code in posst above, can you help me? @SeanKendle

Comment: So, I'm not sure you're understanding my code. Why are you attempting to add the return of a function that doesn't return anything to an array?

Comment: I have provided an updated answer