# Functions with Variable Arguments in javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arguments

I need and advice.

This is my issue, I have "N" functions.

```
 var FirstOne  = function(){
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: hrefUrl,
        data: JSON2.stringify(option),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",           
        error: function(status){
        },
        success: function(data){    
        }
    });
};

var SecondOne  = function(){

    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: hrefUrl,
        data: JSON2.stringify(option2),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",           
        error: function(status){
        },
        success: function(data){    
        }
    });
};


.............


var NOne  = function(){

    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: hrefUrl,
        data: JSON2.stringify(optionn),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",           
        error: function(status){
        },
        success: function(data){    
        }
    });
};
```

all these function arr pushed in an object which is this .

```
var funcObject= [FirstOne(), SecondOne(), ....... NOne() ];
```

after I am waiting when all Ajax functions are done with and and after I am fine.

```
    $.when.apply($, funcObject).done(function (a1, a2, ...an) {
 //        ..... here already doesn't matter

    });
```

my issue is here:

```
function (a1, a2, ...an)
```

I want to have instead function arguments an object because I do not know how many function is going to be.

So i can edit function object, which is cool `$.when.apply($, fucArr)`, problem is to use variable numbers of arguments .

*PS: Maybe I can use  "apply" or "call" for these arguments as well?*

Can someone give me an idea here. Thanks A lot guys!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allowing javascript function to accept any number of arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583044/allowing-javascript-function-to-accept-any-number-of-arguments) and [many others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+variable+number+of+arguments).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can access all arguments passed to a method using [the `arguments` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) eg:

```
function () {
  Console.log(arguments); //arguments is an array
}
```

[The apply method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) can be used to use these arguments in another function call:

```
function () {
  someFunction.apply(this, arguments);
}
```